# iFogSim Simulation Termination

Tags: scheduled-tasks, simulation, scheduling, fog, cloudsim

I have been using CloudSim for task scheduling on Cloud and now scheduling tasks in iFogSim as well. The problem I am facing is that the simulation does not execute the instruction of CloudSim.stopSimulation(); and anything after that is not executed.

All the example programs given in iFogSim are behaving in the same manner. How can I print any results on the console at the end of simulation?

Thanks.

I tried to print just after the CloudSim.startSimulation() but it did not work. Further I also checked inside the startSimulation() to look for any place where I can print my results, but all in vain. I have also checked the exceptions for NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, and Exception and none are thrown.